# i want to use retrofit to establish connection in my android application. Am i correct?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I want to add retrofit to establish connection using Android Studio 2.2.3.  Is the following code correct?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: If you are asking  on how to import retrofit library into your project, yes you are correct, however there's a latest version, `2.5.0` according to their documentation https://square.github.io/retrofit/#download

Comment: you are using older versions of most of the libraries, use the latest available ones.